# why does a search in contacts using full name in lowercase not find the contact?

Tags: contacts, search

Example: I have a contact Leo Bakx. 
The following searches find the contact successfully: leo; bakx; Leo Bakx.
However the search leo bakx (all lower case) results in no match found.
The search %leo bakx% also results in no match found.

We are running version 4.6.1.
Automatic wildcards is enabled.
Individual display name format = {contact.individual_prefix}{
Individual sort name format = {contact.last_name}{, }{contact.first_name}{

We are an organisation with a large turnover in users (mainly young people used to the convenience of throwing anything into google) so inconsistencies are confusing for them and a user-unfriendly work around would not be helpful.

I am a (non-IT) generalist so hopefully there is a simple solution :-). Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are all these searches using the search box at the top left, i.e. as part of the black menu bar? Do they perform the same on the basic search form? It almost sounds like a mysql issue - can you tell us which version you are using?

Comment: Hi, version is in post: 4.6.1 or do you mean something else??

Comment: I am using pull down menu search -> find contacts = basic search.  'leo bakx' in search box top left also does not find contact. Advanced search with simple 'leo bakx' does not find contact. As non-techie mysql issue doesn't mean much to me, even after google, so please advise if this is something I should get someone in my organisation to look into or whether this is something requiring a fix from within civi community.

Comment: My question was not clear - I meant which version of mysql.

Comment: I don't know whether the case-insensitivity is normally handled by mysql or in the code, but if it's supposed to be done in mysql (as I suspect) then some mysql-specific setting might be interfering (for example, if you've got a funny character set or collation, it might not know how to convert cases). http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/case-sensitivity.html

Comment: Thank-you Alan. I will ask our 'IT' guy about the version of mysql.

Comment: Better than that, send him to this thread. It's not just the version, it's also the collation and other configuration pieces that might be at issue.